# Database_url not set in python code

Tags: python, database, postgresql, output, jupyter-notebook

!pip install ipython-sql

%load_ext sql

!pip install psycopg2

import dj_database_url

import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = {'default':dj_database_url.config(default='postgresql://postgres:Roha11*@localhost:5432/postgres')}

["DATABASE_URL not set" this is what I'm getting after each output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4boTC.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `%%sql` magic is looking for an environment variable or a parameter to the `%%sql` command - you have provided neither. Changing the first line of the cell to

```
%%sql postgresql://postgres:Roha11*@localhost:5432/postgres
```

is one way to fix your problem.

You should put the error text in as part of your question, it makes it easier to answer, and better for people that see the question later.

Comment: it will cause an error
 " UsageError: %%sql is a cell magic, but the cell body is empty. Did you mean the line magic %sql (single %)? "

Comment: The linked image is to a cell that uses %%sql, so I don't see why you downvoted my response.

Comment: i have the same problem, however i supply the db url as parameter to %sql. my db url is sqlite:// , that should be universally available in python.